# Make User Control load before page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 parts to my site, Site Master, User Control (inside Site Master) and General page.

When a user logs in they are redirected to the General Page. The User Control is a dropdownlist of different accounts (Auto select first account) that get's their username and runs stored procedure to pull their information into a `SiteID` session Variable.

Then in the General page I set all the labels to the users information. with this code.

```
            if (Session["SiteID"] != null)
        {
            SiteID = int.Parse(Session["SiteID"].ToString());
            PopulateAccountData();
            PopulateAccountInformation2();
            PopulateSiteNodes();
            PopulateSiteMap();
        }

        else
        {
            LabelSiteName.Text = "No Site Selected";

        }
```

The problem is when the page loads for the first time it does not have the `Session["SiteID"]`, I have to hit refresh for everything to load.

I am new to ASP.net so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but how do I get everything to load the first time?

Comment: Don't let the UserControl bind itself from `Page_Load` but `DataBind` it from the page when it should. This also enables to lazy load the controls. The page is the controller not the `UserControl`. So provide a public method in the `UserControl` that you can call from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use : IsPostBack

Look : //www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1083

Comment: I'm not sure how putting it in a ispostback would fix the problem. Are you saying put my code I posted above in ispostback { }. The usercontrol allows them to select different account to choose from which does a postback. I guess I don't follow you, sorry.